# ASP.NET MVC Fluent Validation doesn't work on the client side for view model's property which is another type of class

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I've an ASP.NET MVC application using Fluent Validation. Basically there is a view model Book which has an author as a property on it, like:

```
class Book {
    string Title { get; set; }
    Author Author { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Author {
    string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

On the view there is a field for the ***Book.Author.Name***.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Author.Name)
```

There is Fluent Validation rule set up for the Book view model something like this

```
RuleFor(book => book.Author.Name).NotEmpty();
```

Then I find that this validation won't be fired for the ***Book.Author.Name*** field on client side. When inspecting the field's HTML markup, I found that no validation data attributes have been generated. Seems like Fluent Validation cannot handle the multiple level structure properly to generate the client side validation markups. But after it is posted back to the server, the server side validation fires as expected for this field. How can I get the validation fired on the client side?

Comment: Have you tried just using a `[Required]` attribute on `Name` to see if the `data-val-*` attributes are being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually to work around this problem, I had to create a **custom editor template** for the **Author** class, and a **separate Fluent Validator** for the Author class with all the rules I needed for the properties on the Author class. This approach worked perfect in this case. The client side validation could be fired as expected this time, and so does the server side as well.

By the way, I've also tried to create a **partial view** instead of a custom editor template for the Author class. The client side validation was able to be fired, but after post back the partial view couldn't be bound to the **Book.Author** for the controller's action method.